# Power BI: Slicer for last 24 hours and 7 days

Tags: filter, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Gone through various forums and other similar questions but none has worked for me!

I got Timestamp column in this format: `DD:MM:YYY HH:MM:SS PM/AM`

So how do I create a calculated column that dynamically evaluates the last 24 hours from the refresh time of 8:00 AM daily morning (i.e., it should consider the last 24 hours from previous day 8:00 AM to refresh time 8:00 AM today.

Likewise, the last 7 days too?

I have tried following (for last 24 hours) which I got from https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Only-show-last-24-hours-from-6am/td-p/109226
Power bi forum question.

Measure:

```
minTime = 
var temp= NOW()
return
if(HOUR(temp)>=8,temp,DATE(YEAR(temp),MONTH(temp),DAY(temp)-1)+TIME(8,MINUTE(temp),SECOND(temp)))
```

Table column:

```
New Table= FILTER(ALL(TABLE),[Date]>=[minTime]&&[Date]<=Now())
```

But it is giving me an error as

> The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be
>   converted to a scalar value.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.Could you find any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this -  In my case I imported IIS logs after converting them to CSV files.

For me I think there was about 100 log files from 1/2 dz servers in the farm

1. Import your data
2. The columns available were LogFilename  RowNumber   date    time    s-ip    cs-method cs-uri-stem   cs-uri-query    s-port  cs-username c-ip    cs(User-Agent)  sc-status   sc-substatus    sc-win32-status time-taken
3. My **Time** value looked like this hh:mm:ss - but I wanted to get how many per hour
4. Add a new column "PerHour = Hour(Teams[time])"  - Teams is the table name and time is the column name and PerHour is the NEW column name
   Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/dax/hour-function-dax

Now I have a column and I can do a count for how may time the occurrence happened in that hour

[image: Screenshot]